# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: CMMotionManager with SFML

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sfml

I have been trying to build my SFML app for iOS but I keep running into hurdles. The latest of which is an error that I don't understand, I do not work on Mac much and therefore don't know what most of the errors mean. This specific error seems to be something to do with SFML itself. Is there anything I can do about that? Below is the error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in libsfml-window-s.a(SFAppDelegate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I located CMMotionManager inside of SFML source, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
@property (nonatomic) CMMotionManager* motionManager;
```

Any help is much appreciated, please let me know if there is anything else you need to solve this problem, again, I don't know what most of the errors produced by XCode mean, so I don't know what to provide.

UPDATE:
Someone over on the SFML forums stated that it is possible I just forgot to link to the CoreMotion framework, I will try that as soon as I get back to my computer, and hopefully update this post again with the solution.

Comment: Do you have the `64bit` version of the SFML library installed?

Comment: You can only get the iOS version through building the source by yourself. They provide all the project settings and whatnot through CMake, so I'm not sure, but most likely if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I did not include the dependencies of `libsfml-window-s.a` in my project. One of the required dependencies was `CoreMotion.framework`.

Answer (score 0):

your `libsfml-window-s.a` is not build for your simulator. your need a binary file which build for simulator(architecture x86_64). Perhaps you should also build another one for arm64&armv7

Comment: My Architectures setting currently has armv6 and armv7, should I add arm64 to that or the valid architectures setting, arm64 is already in there.

Comment: your error tell you that your are using simulator while you  do not have an architecture for the simulator(which is x86_64 architecture).  the arm64 or armv7 or armv6 just is the real phone's architecture,so you can only run the app on your iPhone.